# Cooperative yield in asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I'm running a long CPU-intensive task on a (tornado) webserver. I don't want to offload this task to a thread (for now). How do I correctly "yield" control during this long-running task to the eventloop, so that web requests are still being served (note: I'm using "yield" in a cooperative-scheduling sense here, not in a generator-sense, or the python keyword `yield`).

My suggestion would be to do an `await asyncio.sleep(0)`, however is there a guarantee that this is not just implemented as a NOP? I've been looking for a dedicated function in asyncio library to do this, but so far have been unable to find one.

Example (python 3.5 async/await style):

```
async def long_task():
    for i in range(LARGE_NUMBER):
        do_something(i)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't mentioned in doc, but currently `asyncio.sleep(0)` is common way to do this. You can read full discussion [here](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284). Moreover `asyncio.sleep(0)` was specially [optimized](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284#issuecomment-154159149) to do job. Since this case [has test](https://github.com/python/asyncio/pull/285/commits/f11cc8f1ed12ffaca656ddae35594425c0a86145), I think you might not afraid about behavior.

Comment: Perfect! Linked to the exact discussion I was looking for. As long as the BDFL says that this is the way to do it, I'm happy with it :).